# Apache zeppelin: Spark cluster configuration

Tags: pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I'm a new user of pyspark from Apache Zeppelin 0.7.1 to access my Spark cluster. I configured 2 machines:

- **Machine-1**: Spark Master + 2 workers + Apache Zeppelin
- **Machine-2**: 2 Workers

Situation:

- Cluster works fine if I use pyspark console from the Master (Machine-1).
- When I use Local[*] configuration of Spark, all it's OK from
  Zeppelin.

Following [this](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html) zeppelin documentation, I put spark://Machine-1:7077 at the *master* property of the spark interpreter configuration. Then, some code runs OK from the cells of my Zeppelin Notebook:

```
%spark
sc.version
sc.getConf.get("spark.home")
System.getenv().get("PYTHONPATH")
System.getenv().get("SPARK_HOME")
```

but others RDD trasnformations (for instance) never end:

```
%pyspark
input_file = "/tmp/kddcup.data_10_percent.gz"
raw_rdd = sc.textFile(input_file)
```

What's wrong? Some advice?
Thank you in adance.

Comment: Do you see the job running on the Spark console (machine-1:4040)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually I realised that:

1. Memory and cores parameters for workers are not suitable for my
   cluster. I changed the values in spark-env.sh files and It's
   working!.
2. Configuration parameters in Apache Zeppelin had also some
   mistake (son extra spark modules needed)

Thank you, Greg, for your interest.